# INSERT INTO table IF count(*) < 5

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a MySQL Procedures which will insert data into table if count(*) from the same table is less than 5 rows.

The logic is:

```
Declare @count INT;
SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table);
IF (@count = 1)
INSERT INTO table(item1, item2, item3) VALUES('item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing proper syntax for code block.
It should contain `BEGIN .. END` and `IF ... THEN .. END IF` blocks.

***Example***:

```
BEGIN
  Declare @count INT;
  SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table);
  IF (@count = 1) THEN
    INSERT INTO table(item1, item2, item3) VALUES('item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3');
  END IF;
END;
```

And if you want to insert, only if the count is less than 5 then,
Change:

```
  IF (@count = 1) THEN
```

To:

```
  IF (@count < 5) THEN
```

Comment: I'm getting error on the "IF (@count = 1) THEN" line:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (@broj IS NULL) THEN.

Comment: Sorry, the sql code need to be run in a trigger or procedure. It can work as a simple query.

The code works perfect, without "Declare @count INT;" line.